# Is there a way to specify the URL associated with a "Save Password?" prompt?

Tags: html, forms

I have a Register Account page that prompts a user for their desired username and password.

Register URL:

```
http://example.com/account/register
```

When the user submits the register form, they are asked if they would like to save the password - which is desirable, except that saying Yes to this browser prompt associates the username/password with the Register URL/URI.

I need to figure out how to associate that saved password to the actual login URL of:

```
http://example.com/account/login
```

Is there a way of doing this? Or, if this is not possible, is there a way of disabling the Save Password prompt for the Register page? Of course, I am looking for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Saved passwords are generally associated with a domain name, AFAIK.

Comment: @Slaks is right, username/password combinations are stored per full qualified domain name, in your case they would be stored for `http://example.com` but not for `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to be doing this. It remembers the exact URL from what I'm seeing. I say Yes on the Register page submission, but when I go to login Chrome does not enter the password. Entering the password for the login page triggers another "Save Password?" prompt. I haven't checked other browsers, yet.

Comment: I was sure it worked the way you and @SLaks indicate so I'm puzzled why this is happening.

Comment: Firefox works exactly as you two indicate. The saved username/password is valid for the user's return to /account/login. IE doesn't prompt on the register page at all. Chrome prompts on the register page but doesn't associate the saved username/password to the /account/login page. I've always known the FQDN to be used for this as you two indicate. Maybe there is something wrong with my form, but it's just a basic form. I don't see anything I would change. :S